# Awaiting async tasks instantly vs declaring first and then awaiting

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

Let's look at the following 2 examples:

```cs
public class MyClass 
{
    public async Task Main() 
    {
        var result1 = "";
        var result2 = "";

        var request1 = await DelayMe();
        var request2 = await DelayMe();

        result1 = request1;
        result2 = request2;        
    }

    private static async Task<String> DelayMe()
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        return "";
    }
}
```

And:

```cs
public class MyClass 
{
    public async Task Main() 
    {
        var result1 = "";
        var result2 = "";

        var request1 = DelayMe();
        var request2 = DelayMe();

        result1 = await request1;
        result2 = await request2;        
    }

    private static async Task<String> DelayMe()
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        return "";
    }
}
```

In the first example shows how you would typically write `async await` code where one thing happens after the other and awaited properly.

The second one is first calling the `async Task` method but it's `await`ing it later.

The first example takes a bit over `4000ms` to execute because the `await` is computing the first request before it makes the second; but the second example takes a bit over `2000ms`. This happens because the `Task` actually starts running as soon as the execution steps over the `var request1 = DelayMe();` line which means that `request1` and `request2` are running in parallel. At this point it looks like the `await` keyword just ensures that the `Task` is computed.

The second approach feels and acts like a `await Task.WhenAll(request1, request2)`, but in this scenario, if something fails in the 2 requests, you will get an exception instantly instead of waiting for everything to compute and then getting an `AggregateException`.

My question is that is there a drawback (performance or otherwise) in using the second approach to run multiple `await`able `Task`s in parallel when the result of one doesn't depend on the execution of the other? Looking at the lowered code, it looks like the second example generates an equal amount of `System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1`per awaited item while the first one doesn't. Is this still going through the`async await` state-machine flow?

Comment: I can't see any drawbacks, but if I was doing this for non-dependent tasks, I would use `Task.WhenAll()`.  In some instances you might just want one of the tasks to complete (one might be a timeout), in which case you could use `Task.WhenAny()`.

Comment: I suspect the *actual* problem behind this question is something completely different. The obvious problem with the two awaits is that you may have to wait for the slowest task to finish before getting any exceptions any tasks that finished earlier. If you care about such things though you shouldn't be composing tasks this way. An early abort can be accomplished by using a CancellationTokenSource for example that will be signalled if any of the asynchronous operations decides to abort.

Comment: If you need to call eg 3 different services for data, instead of awaiting at the top level for any failures, you could pass a CancellationToken to the worker functions that will be signalled if any of them catches an exception. This will allow the other workers to exit gracefully. Otherwise you'd have to wait for all of them to complete with no way of aborting them

Comment: @Oliver The problem with when all is that if one of them fail in the meantime you will only get the exception when every other task is also completed. That goes against the fail fast policy that I follow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> if something fails in the 2 requests, you will get an exception instantly instead of waiting for everything to compute and then getting an AggregateException.

If something fails in the *first* request, then yes. If something fails in the *second* request, then no, you wouldn't check the second request results until that task is `await`ed.

> My question is that is there a drawback (performance or otherwise) in using the second approach to run multiple awaitable Tasks in parallel when the result of one doesn't depend on the execution of the other? Looking at the lowered code, it looks like the second example generates an equal amount of System.Threading.Tasks.Task1per awaited item while the first one doesn't. Is this still going through theasync await` state-machine flow?

It's still going through the state machine flow. I tend to recommend `await Task.WhenAll` because the intent of the code is more explicit, but there are some people who don't like the "always wait even when there are exceptions" behavior. The flip side to that is that `Task.WhenAll` always collects all the exceptions - if you have fail-fast behavior, then some exceptions could be ignored.

Regarding performance, concurrent execution would be better because you can do multiple operations concurrently. There's no danger of threadpool exhaustion from this because `async`/`await` does not use additional threads.

As a side note, I recommend using the term "asynchronous concurrency" for this rather than "parallel", since to many people "parallel" implies parallel processing, i.e., `Parallel` or PLINQ, which would be the wrong technologies to use in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Stephen. One question before I accept this answer. Since the `var request1 = DelayMe();` is actually running the task as soon as the execution steps over this code how will this task run? Will a threadpool thread pick this task and run it and then when it hit the await line it will be awaited?

Comment: @NickChapsas: Tasks do not necessarily need to "run" anywhere. More specifically, [Delegate Tasks run; Promise Tasks do not](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/a-tour-of-task-part-3-status.html). `async` and `await` are just [managing responses to tasks completing](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html). For your example, `Task.Delay` uses a timer, so there's no thread blocked for that delay. This is the [usually the case for task-returning methods](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).

Comment: I am not asking about await tasks. I am asking about the good old Tasks without any await async. In the second example before the task is being awaited it starts running like a good old C# Task here var request1 = DelayMe(); not as a promise. It is later awaited but it might have completed running at that point so the await doesn’t do anything other than ensuring it’s computation.

Comment: @NickChapsas: Delegate tasks will run on whatever scheduler you run them on. E.g., `Task.Run` will run code on a thread pool thread, and `StartNew`/`Start` will run on the current task scheduler unless you pass a different one.

Answer (score -1):

The drawback of using the second approach to run multiple awaitable tasks in parallel is that the parallelism is not obvious. And not obvious parallelism (implicit multithreading in other words) is dangerous because the bugs that could be introduced are notoriously inconsistent and sporadically observed. Lets suppose that the actual `DelayMe` running in the production environment was the one bellow:

```
private static int delaysCount = 0;

private static async Task<String> DelayMe()
{
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    return (++delaysCount).ToString();
}
```

Sequentially awaited calls to `DelayMe` will return increasing numbers. Parallelly awaited calls will occasionally return the same number.

Comment: I'm more concerned about threadpool starvation tbh. I would have to ensure that the tasks that spin up are not emptying the thread pool since the system will experience heavy load periods and won't scale appropriately. I would also want to know what the impact of using `await Task.WhenAll` would be to make it clearer.

Comment: Tasks running on threadpool threads are intended for sub-second workloads. If some of your tasks are long running then you should consider starting them with the [TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions) setting, to make them run in a dedicated thread.